# Notational Ambiguity Regarding Functional Limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definition

$\def\R{\mathbf{R}}$
**I'm familiar with the rigorous definitions of functional limits, continuity, and differentiability. What I want to know is the notation and some subtleties regarding their definitions.**

**Definition** (Convergence of functions at a point). Let $X$ be a
subset of $\R$, let $f : X → \R$ be a function, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, $x_0$
be an adherent point of $E$, and let $L$ be a real number. We say that $f$
converges to $L$ at $x_0$ in $E$, and write $\lim_{x→x_0;x∈E}{f(x)}= L$, iff for every $ε > 0$,
there exists a $δ > 0$ such that $|f(x) − L| ≤ ε$ for all $x ∈ E$ such that
$|x − x_0| \leq δ$. If $f$ does not
converge to any number $L$ at $x_0$, we say that $f$ diverges at $x_0$, and leave
$\lim_{x→x_0;x∈E}{f(x)}$ undefined.

> **Remark $\mathbf{9.3.7}$, Analysis I, Terrence Tao.** In many cases we will omit the set $E$ from the above notation (i.e., we will just say that $f$
> converges to $L$ at $x_0$, or that $\lim_{x→x_0}{ f(x)} = L$, although
> this is slightly dangerous. For instance, it sometimes makes a
> difference whether $E$ actually contains $x_0$ or not. To give an
> example, if $f : \R → \R$ is the function defined by setting $f(x) = 1$
> when $x = 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ when $x \neq 0$, then one has
> $\lim_{x→0;x∈\R \setminus \{0\}}{ f(x)} = 0$, but $\lim_{x→0;x∈\R}{f(x)}$
> is undefined. Some authors only define the limit
> $\lim_{x→x_0;x∈E}{ f(x)}$ when $E$ does not contain $x_0$ (so that
> $x_0$ is now a limit point of $E$ rather than an adherent point), or
> would use $\lim_{x→x_0;x∈E}{ f(x)}$ to denote what we would call
> $\lim_{x∈x_0;x∈E\setminus\{x_0\}}{ f(x)}$, but we have chosen a
> slightly more general notation, which allows the possibility that $E$
> contains $x_0$.

Looking across several books and websites, people seem to have their own opinion of the notation and what it means, so I want to establish a couple of things:

1. What is the "standard definition" of a functional limit is with what notation? (be specific in domains of the variable and which kind of points are allowed)
2. Based on this "standard convention", which limits would be defined/undefined in degenerate cases, eg. $g: \emptyset \to \R$, or cases where there are arbitrarily close points where the function is not defined (eg. $\lim_{x \to 0}{\sqrt{x}}$)
3. How does the "standard definition" translate in terms of continuity/differentiability? Are functions say, always continuous at their isolated points?
4. (Misc.) Are the terms "undefined", "does not exist", "diverges", "does not converge" (etc.) when dealing with limits the same in meaning? Can we just get by by using only "undefined"? If the limit "equals" $\infty$, do we say that the limit "exists" but isn't "defined"? What is the convention regarding the existence of infinite limits?